# D3 Zoomable Pack Layout hides last inner bubble

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to have an onclick event on the last inner bubble. I've encountered 2 issues, the first one is that if I remove this line:

```
.label, .node--root, .node--leaf { pointer-events: none; }
```

It zooms in the last inner bubble I clicked but the text disappears. How can I add an onclick event to the last inner child?
Heres my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/23yaf9qd/

I tried with jquery but it doesn't work

```
$("circle[id^='circle']").click(function () {
     //my rest of code
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when you click a leaf? It should zoom on it and show its name, or do nothing?

Comment: When I click a leaf I want it to execute a function that'll take as a parameter the ID and open a dialogbox with info that's based on that ID. I know how to do create the dialog box and fill it with data. I just need to enable the click event on the leaf and not hide the label text of that leaf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the name of inner nodes when they are zoomed in, you can add a field `showText` to your data, as follows:

```
  transition.selectAll("text")
     .each(function(d) {d.showText=( d.parent === focus || ( d === focus && !d.children))})
```

Then you can use `d.showText`instead of testing for the parent (see https://jsfiddle.net/epkrgdok/ )

For your other question: the following line should work

```
  d3.selectAll(".node--leaf").on("click",function(){alert("you've just clicked a leaf")});
```

however it seems to be a problem in your jsfiddle (it does register an event to the nodes, but it triggers a "raes is not defined" error, which you had already before, and I have no clue about *that*.